# Is there a way to disable "Drag and Drop" in all views of my Android app?

Tags: java, android, textview

In the Errors and ANR section of the Google Play Console this error is frequent in users whose devices have Android 10 or higher:

> Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Drag shadow dimensions must
> be positive   at android.view.View.startDragAndDrop (View.java:25464)
> at android.widget.Editor.startDragAndDrop (Editor.java:1183)   at
> android.widget.Editor.performLongClick (Editor.java:1209)   at
> android.widget.TextView.performLongClick (TextView.java:12292)   at
> android.view.View.performLongClick (View.java:7222)   at
> android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run (View.java:27374)   at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)   at
> android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:241)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7617)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke   at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> (RuntimeInit.java:492)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> (ZygoteInit.java:941)

The error message doesn't let me know where the error occurs, but from what I've investigated it seems to be caused by trying to "Drag and Drop", in this case on a TextView, from what this line of the message says of mistake:

```
android.widget.TextView.performLongClick (TextView.java:12292).
```

The functionality of "Drag and Drop" does not interest me. My TextViews allow the following and I do want to keep that:

1. Select part of the text or all of the text to copy, paste, share
2. Increase or enlarge the size of the text by doing "Pinch to Zoom", using a custom class that extends from `TextView`
3. Have clickable links

All three things works fine. So how can I disable the ability to "Drag and Drop" all my views or my TextViews, without preventing me from being able to do the three things mentioned above? I ask about all my views because I also use RecyclerView, Menus, etc. and apparently the users can do "Drag and Drop" in them too, but I'm not interested in doing "Drag and Drop" in any case.

This is how I set my TextView in any Fragment of my application:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements TextToSpeechCallback {

    private ZoomTextView mTextView;

    private void setConfiguration() {

        mViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        mTextView = binding.include.tvZoomable;
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        float fontSize = Float.parseFloat(prefs.getString("font_size", "18"));
        String fontFamily = String.format(new Locale("es"),"fonts/%s",prefs.getString("font_name", "robotoslab_regular.ttf"));
        Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(requireActivity().getAssets(),fontFamily);
        mTextView .setTypeface(tf);
        mTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize);
        hasInvitatory = prefs.getBoolean("invitatorio", false);
        isVoiceOn = prefs.getBoolean("voice", true);
        if (isVoiceOn) {
            sbReader = new StringBuilder(VOICE_INI);
        }
    }
    
    // ...

}
```

And the XML of my `TextView` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_preferences"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
    >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.example.utils.ZoomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_Zoomable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="50dp"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppTheme.DisplayBody"
                />
        </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is there a way to disable the possibility of "Drag and Drop", either from the XML, or programmatically?